# Could not create player! javafx

Tags: java, javafx, java-module

I'm trying to make a simple video player using JavaFX. I'm using IntelliJ that has Maven with all plugins. I'm running on Corretto SDK 18.0.2.

But when I build it and choose the file I get this error:

```
com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
```

I'm on Windows.

```
Apr 08, 2023 2:37:26 PM javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement processValue
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 19 by JavaFX runtime of version 18.0.2
FilePath is- file:D:\Java\NetflixProject\src\main\java\Test\VideoTest.mp4
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8797)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3881)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1874)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2607)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:411)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:301)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:450)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:424)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:449)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:551)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@18.0.2/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:184)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at javafx.base@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:84)
    at javafx.fxml@18.0.2/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1854)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.media@19/javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:147)
    at javafx.media@19/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:519)
    at javafx.media@19/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:422)
    at com.example.netflixproject/Controllers.VideoPlayerController.handleButtonAction(VideoPlayerController.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.media@19/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:297)
    at javafx.media@19/com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.media@19/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:475)
    ... 56 more
```

I made a file chooser and the GUI opens so after I choose the file the error appears and nothing displays in my media view:

```java
package Controllers;

import DAO.EpisodeDAO2;
import Utils.DataHolder;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class VideoPlayerController implements Initializable {
    public MediaView mvVideo;
    @FXML
    public MediaPlayer mpVideo;
    @FXML
    public Media mediaVideo;
    public Slider SliderTime;
    public Button ButtonPPR;
    public HBox HboxVolume;
    public Label LabelVolume;
    public Slider SliderVolume;
    public Label LabelCurrentTime;
    public Label LabelTotalTime;
    public Label LabelSpeed;
    public Label LabelFullScreen;

    private boolean atEndOfVideo = false;
    private boolean isPalying = false;
    private boolean isMuted = false;

    private ImageView ivPlay;
    private ImageView ivPause;
    private ImageView ivRestart;
    private ImageView ivVolume;
    private ImageView ivMute;
    private ImageView ivFullScreen;
    @FXML
    public void handleButtonAction() throws Exception{
        FileChooser fc= new FileChooser();
        FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extensionFilter= new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Video files with mp4 extension only.", "*.mp4");
        fc.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter);

        File file= fc.showOpenDialog(null);
        String filePath = file.toURI().toString();

        if(filePath!= null) {
            System.out.println("FilePath is- "+filePath);
            Media media= new Media(filePath);
            mpVideo= new MediaPlayer(media);
            mvVideo.setMediaPlayer(mpVideo);

            mpVideo.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }
}
```

Comment: JavaFX media is at version 19 and other JavaFX modules are at version 18.0.2.  All JavaFX versions should be the same.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing mvVideo before setting mpVideo with the media file you selected. To fix this, you can move the initialization of mvVideo after creating the MediaPlayer with the selected file.

For handleButtonAction method try this:

```java
@FXML
public void handleButtonAction() throws Exception{
    FileChooser fc= new FileChooser();
    FileChooser.ExtensionFilter extensionFilter= new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("Video files with mp4 extension only.", "*.mp4");
    fc.getExtensionFilters().add(extensionFilter);

    File file= fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    String filePath = file.toURI().toString();

    if(filePath!= null) {
        System.out.println("FilePath is- "+filePath);
        Media media= new Media(filePath);
        mpVideo= new MediaPlayer(media);

        // move initialization of mvVideo after creating the MediaPlayer
        mvVideo= new MediaView(mpVideo);
        mvVideo.setFitWidth(DataHolder.WIDTH);
        mvVideo.setFitHeight(DataHolder.HEIGHT);
        mvVideo.setPreserveRatio(false);
        mvVideo.setSmooth(true);

        mpVideo.setAutoPlay(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same issue